# Use definition of limit to prove..

Tags: analysis, limits

Question: Let $x_n = 1+\frac{5+n}{n^2}$. Use the definition to prove that 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n = 1$$

I know from the definition, that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$, so I start with:
$$|1+ \frac{5+n}{n^2} -1| = |\frac{5+n}{n^2}| <\epsilon$$

Then I do a bunch of algebra and I can't figure out a closed form solution for $n$. help!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For $n\ge 5,$ you have $\frac{5+n}{n^2}\le\frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac2n.$ How large must $n$ be in order that $\frac2n<\epsilon$? How can you ensure that $n$ is this large and also $\ge 5$?

Comment: Can I start the sequence at n-5? so the sequence will be $$x_{n-5}=1+\frac{5+(n-5)}{(n-5)^2}$$?

Comment: How do you define $x_5$ then?

Comment: True, how about $x_{n-4}$? This will take care of the n=0 I think?

Comment: @user12279: Further hint: $n\ge\max\{N_1,N_2\}.$

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm sorry I'm not sure how to proceed with that hint. Intuitively I would have either $N_1$ or $N_2$ be greater than or equal to 5.. but I'm not sure how to get that.. Could I say that $|N_1 - N_2| \leq 5$?

Comment: @user12279: Let $N_0$ ba an integer $\geq\frac2\epsilon,$ and put $N=\max\{5,N_0\}.$ Then what can you say for $n>N$?